# How to define array with alternating types in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

I would like to define an array type that allows different types depending on position, but in a repeating, alternating manner as found in some data structures.

Example:

```
[A, B, A, B, ...]
[A, B, C, A, B, C, ...]
```

Is this possible?

I know that I can define it for arrays with a fixed number of elements like above (without the ellipsis), and

```
(A | B)[]
```

would on the other hand allow any element to be either of type A or B.

I tried these:

```
[(A, B)...]
[...[A, B]]
[(A, B)*]
```

Comment: You can't. Tuples have different types by index but fixed length, arrays don't let you define alternating types. It seems like your data structure is weird, why not use e.g. `[A, B][]`, an array of tuples?

Comment: Thanks. :-( It's for Elasticsearch bulk operations.

Comment: This is a good question. Wish there was a solution to this.

Comment: This question might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67315596/define-a-type-of-alternating-pairs/69787886#69787886

Comment: @Arc could you please send me the link to elastic documentation with such requirement?

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine it's alternating actions/metadata and source data (the latter is optional, but in my case my bulk ops are alternating). And no, your linked question is a duplicate of this one, which is older :-)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Answer (score 9):

I came up with something that "works", but it's kinda crazy:

```js
type Alternating<T extends readonly any[], A, B> =
  T extends readonly [] ? T
  : T extends readonly [A] ? T
  : T extends readonly [A, B, ...infer T2]
    ? T2 extends Alternating<T2, A, B> ? T : never
  : never
```

This requires TypeScript 4.1+ because of the recursive conditional type.

---

Naive usage requires duplicating the value as a literal type for the `T` parameter, which is not ideal:

```js
const x: Alternating<[1, 'a', 2], number, string> = [1, 'a', 2]
```

That seems strictly worse than just writing out `[number, string, number]` as the type. However with the help of a dummy function it's possible to avoid repetition:

```js
function mustAlternate<T extends readonly any[], A, B>(
  _: Alternating<T, A, B>
): void {}

const x = [1, 'a', 2] as const
mustAlternate<typeof x, number, string>(x)
```

[Here's a live demo with some test cases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNsCAnAdgQ2ASxQcwDwAqUEAHoigCYDOUSEaFA9inCFGiiANoC6ANLAEAhAHxQAvACgoUIqXLVa9Jiza8oAflnSoALlnEyESjToNmrKFxg9N2mfrlGTS86qsxhAgHS-sAM2RZACYeHRktAmDDBRp4RFQMbHwogU8oUTsifRQIADdkHRz8wsl-AFcUAGMsZigAW3KqYHjkdERCGONFMxVLDm5+QQyRAAodAH19VsSsXEI04RFJAEp9PMZMCigAbwBfSUkq5mb2CSsARgEAcjRr2zQaY5RmyUbmmfaIPFBIRn92AIUOV6gAjZACZpIZJjNArN5NFoINoYb6-CD-QFQKHJIEg8FIWErKAAehJ2IAFoxynBtv40Jg4EcTsB2AAGHL4oLidhcNlhZ6nNAXfQ43DnNBcC4ClnsoQMUXAaHinmS-mk8lUKk0ukMpmC1nC+UUTlg7m86UaynU2lQemMw4GqCg87qR5QA0Ij7I2Zo8AYgGgvFmpCQpUw0ag+HMl6sqquy3uz3vJEJL4-f2YqrBglh5U4MZVaNO7Y8qU3O4CULsJ4sr2plEddGYig5iHY8O4MYUYuy6Blq5QW7XKs3UH3Gseuspz6ojN-AEQNuhjv5sYQXuxu2u4cPWux+uzpuZgH+Zd5iP+Ylk606u16x2ynA7ytD8d7qcHmc+9PNgE4c9VwjHBr01bVbXtJkY1OCkEwrEcoGCMcEOuKoJyTadESPP0FygClALFAtRgpUDbwgh8gA).

---

I wouldn't actually recommend relying on this in typical codebases (it's awkward to use and the error messages are terrible). I mostly just worked through it to see how far the type system could be stretched.

If anyone has suggestions for how to make it less wonky, I'm all ears!

---

#### Update

If you're using TypeScript 4.9+ you can ditch the `mustAlternate` function in favor of the `satisfies` operator. [Here's an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNsCAnAdgQ2ASxQcwDwAqUEAHoigCYDOUSEaFA9inCFGiiANoC6ANLAEAhAHxQAvACgoUIqXLVa9Jiza8oAflnSoALlnEyESjToNmrKFxg9N2mfrlGTS86qsxhAgHS-sAM2RZACYeHRktAmDDBRp4RFQMbHwogU8oUTsifRQIADdkHRz8wskAY2YqYHYJKwBGAQByNEbbNBoKlCrJNCgqJKp-TAg4hGR0LFw8UEhGf3YBFABXAFsAI2QBKqRkkR6+gaGR2DHEyfwZiDmFvuAd3EXVjaQxAHpXvoALRiW4Cih-GhMHBypVqmgAAw5J5BcTsLgQsKdKrsOr6bbJWpoLh1JFg9gQoQMdF3TFw7GIqDvL4-P4AoEg5HgupEijQ9aw+G4qkfKjfX7-QHAySgrrVNa1dTtKBMyQS-pYQbDUYJCbJabgK7zNaPDlILak3B7UUosqS7nS2VmhWYJXHeLjJJTS7XMq654G+44Y1MqD-OE4potAShdgdMGSf42u0qx3nDWzeYUd2bW5en346ABhpQZqNENNNatMMyiPQaNHWNndUu+YQFP6tO7EW++YBvNtcNiyTzCvKk6qp0XTXXfwNz27Hk0gX04Um6o4SV5wvFy0Rxd9+2nNXOkfzHDjptGqd82mChkt-Gfc1B-NQYIrpplVdd7rXzdVnfDxNQT6HjHHtSp4zkKIJAA).

Answer (score 6):

Alternative approach:

```js
type MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY = 50

type Mapped<
    Tuple extends Array<unknown>,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = [],
    Count extends ReadonlyArray<number> = []
    > =
    (Count['length'] extends MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY
        ? Result
        : (Tuple extends []
            ? []
            : (Result extends []
                ? Mapped<Tuple, Tuple, [...Count, 1]>
                : Mapped<Tuple, Result | [...Result, ...Tuple], [...Count, 1]>)
        )
    )



type Result = Mapped<[string, number, number[]]>

// 3 | 6 | 9 | 12 | 15 | 18 | 21 | 24 | 27 | 30 | 33 | 36 | 39 | 42 | 45 | 48
type Test = Result['length']

/**
 * Ok
 */
const test1: Result = ['a', 42, [1]]
const test2: Result = ['a', 42, [1], 'b', 43, [2]]

/**
 * Fail
 */
const test3:Result = ['a'] // error

const fn = <T, U>(tuple: Mapped<[T, U]>) => tuple

fn([42, 'hello']) // ok
fn([42, 'hello','sdf']) // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20211101#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsgQQBoEk4FU4H0EBlcDyA6gKIAiWAQgegHJkIBKAmjALwwCsADMKJLDgBDCNAAmAHmAwZMACoBXCABtYUAB4goAOzEBnGAgBORoWAkLtAa20B7AO7aAfABppsxlD0LlIGBq1dA2NTc0sbB2d2GABtAF03WRgAYVtLPwCdfRhPITFbbWUwELMJbQUAWwAjKCMnaPj3GXq2JpgAClT0mIByVW0AcxAACx64-00sg0RUDGw8QlIKajoGFjakgH4crx8QDdkALg7FFTVJoNi4g6SZbcbbx5hj9s9vXwnA7Ien3+3hURQSSnVQueRKUGxAB0MK62hAYIAjHEnDdfs94CJxBIQVAwW89jAAD7QmEE3xgmFQ3EJUlQuEImDIpwASjRbKSbL4-GgO3efg4AOxMT0ICMAEtBmDytVaii+AB6BUwABMxJgABZ1QA2dUADnViO4hrVJMRWrNurNBpJKuNttNqo1PNgci8Ar5e16-SGo2ufAAxgVRTAAGbaaI4sHoJztEAQqDHIVAiQxOTRlEs9j1eNnPjh9oxDUqsE9YZQZTKWxjLNKmC2KzAAtFkswMsVqs9Fw9PRiUM1mB1jTQANaMT+Ey2IxAA)

**`Mapped`** - ugly name but does the job :D. Creates a union of all allowed states of the tuple. Each allowed tuple state has a length which can be divided by 3: `length%3===0 // true`. You can define any tuple you want, with 4 values, 5 etc ...

Every iteration I\m increasing `Count` array by 1. That's how I know when to stop recursive iteration.