# Define an array type recursive with two types and some rules

Tags: javascript, typescript

I hava an array with two types, which the odd index is always `TypeA` and the even index is always `TypeB`.

According to the description, the array always has even `length`, never have odd length.

> The data structure of array must be so.
>
> And this structure is from marijnh's [orderedmap](https://github.com/marijnh/orderedmap) module.

```
// array
[A, B, A, B, A, B, ...]

// How to define it's type?
```

Comment: Can you make two arrays, one with type A elements and other with type B elements, and then have a method like get_index which takes an index and then returns array1[index/2] if the index is even and array2[floor(index/2)] otherwise?

Comment: @MDude Ah, sorry. The data structure must be so.

Comment: @percy507 why has it to be this way?

Comment: Here you have more similar questions/answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69085069/repeat-multiple-function-arguments/69087323#69087323 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68370968/define-a-recursive-array-of-even-length-in-typescript#answer-68373774 , https://catchts.com/rest-tuples#repeated , https://catchts.com/even-length, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67315596/define-a-type-of-alternating-pairs/69787886#69787886

Comment: @ThomasJunk See the new description.

Comment: @captain-yossarian Thanks. I will check that.

Comment: @percy507 above solutions should not have odd length. You can also write `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY` in a search input and you will get all related solutions

Comment: @captain-yossarian OK. I will public it if I can solve this. 

Answer (score 0):

for this type of array it's better to define two arrays first for the first type and second for the second type but for example if it is char and int you can define it as a int and whenever you want to use it as a char in scanf use %d to scan ascii code of that and use %c in printf to print char of it