# How to create an Interface for adding dynamic values in an array of objects : Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, arraylist, interface, typeerror

I have an array and a string which are like:

```
const array1 = ['id', 'home', 'address']
const string1 = 'isValid'
```

I want to create an array of objects with some operator(string) in between like the following:

```
coupon : [
    {
        reference: ['id'],
    },
    '=',
    {
        reference: ['isValid', 'id'],
    },
    'and',
    {
        reference: ['home'],
    },
    '=',
    {
        reference: ['isValid', 'home'],
    },
    'and',
    {
        reference: ['address'],
    },
    '=',
    {
        reference: ['isValid', 'address'],
    },
]
```

How to create an interface for this, for example if i will add more items in the array1 the array of object will change.

I have created an interface

```
interface IReference {
    reference: string[]
}

interface IReferences {
    coupon: [IReference, string, IReference] | IReference
}
```

Now when I add the value of One element which is like shown below, it's not throwing an error.

```
{
    reference: ['id'],
},
'=',
{
    reference: ['isValid', 'id'],
}
```

But when i add a string in between `'and'`

And then the other elements:

```
{
    reference: ['home'],
},
'=',
{
    reference: ['isValid', 'home'],
}
```

It is throwing an error, I think the interface is not correct. How should i achieve this in Typescript with the interfaces?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61155425/how-to-define-array-with-alternating-types-in-typescript

Comment: ` [IReference, string, IReference] | IReference: string[]` is not valid TypeScript.  Could you make sure your code constitutes a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [the TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/wgrEyW)?

Comment: @jcalz : I have updated the example. Its 'IReference' instead of 'IReference: string[]'