# How do I define TS generic type where each array element is another generic?

Tags: typescript-generics

Suppose I have objects as follows:

```
const a = { propA: 'hello' }
const b = { propB: 'world' }
```

I want to define an array as follows:

```
const arr = [ [a, ["propA"], [b, ["propB"] ]
```

where, in each element (a nested array), the second element is one of the properties of the first element.

I want TS compiler to raise an error when the second element is not a property of the first element, for example, all following should raise an error:

```
const arr = [
  [a, ["propB"], // propB is a property of b, but not of a
  [a, ["propC"], // propC is not a property of a
  [b, ["propA"], // propA is a property of a, but not of b
  [b, ["propD"]  // propD is not a property of b
]
```

How do I define a generic type applicable to `arr`?

Answer (score 0):

It's doable, but due to it's complexity, not recommended (see [other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61155425/how-to-define-array-with-alternating-types-in-typescript))

A cleaner approach would be, to wrap the array elements to an appropriate class.

```js
const a = {propA: 'hello'};
const b = {propB: 'world', propBB: 'lorem'};

class ObjectWithProperties<T> {
    constructor(
        public value: T,
        public properties: (keyof T)[]
    ) {}
}

const objectsWithProperties: ObjectWithProperties<any>[] = [
    new ObjectWithProperties(a, ['propA']),
    new ObjectWithProperties(b, ['propB']),
    new ObjectWithProperties(b, ['propB', 'propBB']),
    // Error: Type '"propA"' is not assignable to type '"propB" | "propBB"'
    new ObjectWithProperties(b, ['propA']),
];
```

The generic type `T` of `value` can then be used to assign the type `(keyof T)[]` to `properties`, which is an array of strings that are property names of the object in `value`.

Comment: The two questions are not related, there is no notion of alternating patterns, it is simply a tuple of entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do such a check like so

```js
const arr = check([
    [a, ["propA"]],
    [b, ["propB"]],
    [a, ["propB"]], // Type '"propB"' is not assignable to type '"propA"'
    [a, ["propC"]], // Type '"propC"' is not assignable to type '"propA"'
    [b, ["propA"]], // Type '"propA"' is not assignable to type '"propB"'
    [b, ["propD"]]  // Type '"propD"' is not assignable to type '"propB"'
]);
```

```js
type Entry = readonly [unknown, readonly string[]];

type Check<T extends readonly Entry[]> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Related<T[K]>
};

type Related<T extends Entry> =
    T extends readonly [infer A, unknown]
    ? [A, (keyof A)[]]
    : never

const check = <const T extends readonly Entry[] & Check<T>>(x: T) => x
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3jADgJxOgggLhgHIALAUwBsKQiYBfAWAChRJYAjJVDbdAIUJEA7iEwUAJrUZNmraDGDlgAay4AeObAAqMMgA8oZMOIgxMZOOPAUAnjACiYKJhsBtALowAZDADCS5TUtAD5ggAo9Qi0ASiRgmD1mZigbdDIHJxcuc0trO1cAVzBlMBAhMAAaMwsrMFsYaEwASzAAcw93AG4kphS0vwCg3QMjE2rcurtHZzd3eOQUZhhlmFcAaRgWmGUyGxAAMxgtd0IAJUo4Q3Eg9bnmOm6ZXtT084pLsmudfUNjU2mXPMlitviM-uNavVXC19mRMDBcFUiiUymB3MDlgB+VaImBhHZ7Q64aIdDEwQhgMgANzhPU08Ew8OQijIKjCrjJrjgVVcACIsDhcLz3O4Kpz2Dz+bw+MLRZzuaspTgZSKqgB6NVHF7EJX8Xm0JqmUqwOAQCBNVpgODsCjpKAgGB9dJEXVCojyyUC9C+WXqzVabUur0+g1GkAms0Wq02u0Op06r1u8We3hC1UwDVa-pB1P6zZhiPmy3W22OuOB3Uy91MFarCWKr0AEVly0zAezuuboZgxvgkeLMbLjorXqrzHc0U6QA)

---

If you need the inferred type to be mutable, consider doing

```js
type Check<T extends readonly Entry[]> = {
    -readonly [K in keyof T]: Related<T[K]>
//  ----------
};
```

---

I realise the question was a little ambiguous, which explains novarx's answer, because there is a syntax error. You could be willing to write

```js
const arr = check([
    a, ["propA"],
    b, ["propB"],
    a, ["propB"], // Type '"propB"' is not assignable to type '"propA"'
    a, ["propC"], // Type '"propC"' is not assignable to type '"propA"'
    b, ["propA"], // Type '"propA"' is not assignable to type '"propB"'
    b, ["propD"]  // Type '"propD"' is not assignable to type '"propB"'
]);
```

This is also possible to check, but you need to prevent TS from widening the inferred type in different spots so you can work with it:

```js
type Entries = readonly (unknown | string[])[];

type Narrow<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? T[K] : Narrow<T[K]> };

type Check<T> =
    T extends readonly [infer A, infer _, ...infer Rest]
    ? [A, (keyof A)[], ...Check<Rest>]
    : T

const check = <T extends Entries>(x: Check<Narrow<T>>) => x
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3jADgJxOgggLhgHIALAUwBsKQiYBfAWAChRJYAjJVDbdAIUJEA7iEwUAJrUZNmraDGDlgAay4AeACowyADyhkw4iDACiYKJgCWZCAD4AFDsIBhJcrUA5OJmxDNt2wBKJFsYHWZmKABPdDJTcysbLkwyOHFwCiiYewBXMGUwECEwGAAfGGgrMABzAG0AXUCGgG4IpmjYmC8fIv8uNFqAaRhLEuUyKJAAMxgNesINIfrtPQMjGAAxPOAoS3AYAH5ZpZhCbt9NJdC6Vpl2mLjXMhU+xGYYD9mV-UNjFLSMllaqMpmRMDBcAAaEZgUHggD60IAdCiQWCYAAlGxQervT5HWpQ7LjSYzXBNerIlFPF5Y6C2XFMT6nWZtOSwbzg5CKZ7Key1PEfODQ2oAIiwOFwospgpg7BF4t4fGlkNlwpgYol-BVMAA9LrZg9iIqcMraJZjIUORAIJZqmA4OwKHEoCAYB04kQTXhRUQ1Qqtc4dfrDZ0vYHfSNLSBrbb7Y7ne63R7jVqpX6mZ95RrvVLKXqDRojeHeOmozArfAbXaHU6Xcni96zbLs5reAARaUfENFsPezvm6OxmsJ+vuxta5tMRrNIA)

This version is not as clean as the first one. There is nothing stopping you from writing `check([a, ["propA"], b, ["propB"], ['propC']])` because we need to infer the first element of each pair as `unknown` and we can't enforce that we are dealing with pairs. However, as soon as you add another object after `'propC'`, the type checker warns you that there is a problem although it's can't quite pinpoint the cause of the problem.